# argparse -- requiring either 2 values or none for an optional argument

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to make an optional argument for a script that can either take no values or 2 values, nothing else. Can you accomplish this using argparse?

```
# desired output:
# ./script.py -a --> works
# ./script.py -a val1 --> error
# ./script.py -a val1 val2 --> works
```

version 1 -- accepts 0 or 1 values:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", nargs="?", const=True, action="store", help="do some action")
args = parser.parse_args()

# output:
# ./script.py -a --> works
# ./script.py -a val1 --> works
# ./script.py -a val1 val2 --> error
```

version 2 - accepts exactly 2 values:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", nargs=2, action="store", help="do some action")
args = parser.parse_args()

# output:
# ./script.py -a --> error
# ./script.py -a val1 --> error
# ./script.py -a val1 val2 --> works
```

How do you combine these 2 different versions so that the script accepts 0 or 2 values for the argument, but rejects it when it only has 1 value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to do your own error checking here. Accept 0 or more value, and reject anything other than 0 or 2:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", nargs='*', action="store", help="do some action")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.action is not None and len(args.action) not in (0, 2):
    parser.error('Either give no values for action, or two, not {}.'.format(len(args.action)))
```

Note that `args.action` is set to `None` when no `-a` switch was used:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", nargs='*', action="store", help="do some action")
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-a', '--action'], dest='action', nargs='*', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='do some action', metavar=None)
>>> args = parser.parse_args([])
>>> args.action is None
True
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['-a'])
>>> args.action
[]
```

Comment: with this solution "./script.py" acts the same as "./script.py -a"

Comment: @xgord: in both cases you'd not want an error. You want an error when you use `./script.py -a foo` or `./script.py -a foo bar baz` and longer.

Comment: @xgord: this check is *not* about handling the `./script.py` case, only about raising an error when `-a` was used but with the wrong number of arguments. What did you expect to happen instead in that case?

Comment: i need to make the distinction between whether -a is called with 0 or 2 args. when it's called with 0, i want to call a particular function with no values. when it's called with 2, i want the function to be called using those values. if -a isn't specified, i'm not calling that function at all

Comment: @xgord: in which case `args.action is None` is true. That's a different case.

Comment: thanks, that was the distinction I was missing. I didn't realize that args.action is set to [] when specified with no values because i was only checking "if (args.action)" which returned false for both args.action=None and args.action=[] making them appear the same.

Comment: How do you explain this argument to your users?

Comment: You can set the default to e.g. `('unspecified',)` or `(None,)`, to distinguish switch not used from no arguments.

Comment: @osa: I'd use an explicit sentinel: `_sentinel = object()`, then `if args.action is _sentinel`.

Answer (score 4):

Just handle that case yourself:

```
parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", nargs='*', action="store", help="do some action")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.action is not None:
    if len(args.action) not in (0, 2):
        parser.error('Specify no or two actions')

    # action was specified but either there were two actions or no action
else:
    # action was not specified
```

Of course you should update the help text in that case so that the user has a chance to know this before running into the error.

Comment: with this solution "./script.py" acts the same as "./script.py -a"

Comment: How is there a practical difference between those two?

Comment: @xgord It actually doesn’t act the same. if you do `./script.py`, `args.action` will be `None`; if you do `./script.py -a`, then `args.action` will be `[]`.

Comment: oh okay. thanks for making that distinction! that's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

Have your option take a single, optional comma-separated string. You'll use a custom type to convert that string to a list and verify that it has exactly two items.

```
def pair(value):
    rv = value.split(',')
    if len(rv) != 2:
        raise argparse.ArgumentParser()
    return rv

parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", nargs='?',
                    type=pair, metavar='val1,val2',
                    help="do some action")
print parser.parse_args()
```

Then you'd use it like

```
$ ./script.py -a
Namespace(action=None)
$ ./script.py -a val1,val2
Namespace(action=['val1','val2'])
$ ./script.py -a val1
usage: tmp.py [-h] [-a [ACTION]]
script.py: error: argument -a/--action: invalid pair value: 'val1'
$ ./script.py -a val1,val2,val3
usage: tmp.py [-h] [-a [ACTION]]
script.py: error: argument -a/--action: invalid pair value: 'val1,val2,val3'
```

You can adjust the definition of `pair` to use a different separator and to return something other than a list (a tuple, for example).

The `metavar` provides a better indication that the argument to `action` is a pair of values, rather than just one.

```
$ ./script.py -h
usage: script.py [-h] [-a [val1,val2]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -a [val1,val2], --action [val1,val2]
                        do some action
```

Answer (score -1):

How about the required argument:`parser.add_argument("-a", "--action", nargs=2, action="store", help="do some action", required=False)`

Comment: This doesn't work, `-a` without any values gives an error because it is not exactly 2 elements. `required=False` is *the default* anyway.

Comment: Optionals (`--like-this -or-this`) are not required by default with argparse.