# Making a group of ArgParse arguments optional

Tags: python, argparse

I have my current code like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('origin_x', help='X origin', type=float)
parser.add_argument('origin_y', help='Y origin', type=float)
parser.add_argument('origin_z', help='Z origin', type=float)
parser.add_argument('file_name', help='File to use')
```

I can call like so, of course:

```
python my_prog.py 0 0 0 foo.txt
```

However, I want also to do this:

```
python my_prog.py foo.txt
```

But not this:

```
python my_prog.py 0 foo.txt
```

Is there any way to do this with the existing API? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30945612/1270789) shows how to do something similar by hand, but is there an automatic way?

Comment: `nargs='?'` makes the argument 'optional'.  But values are assigned by position, not by 'type' or value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post-processing is likely the best bet:

```
parser.add_argument('origin', nargs="*", default=[0., 0., 0.], type=float)
parser.add_argument('file_name', help='File to use')
args = parser.parse_args()
if not len(args.origin) == 3:
    parser.error("you done wrong..")
```

Comment: That seems so simple, and I can expand it easily to cover my additional use case of adding Roll, Pitch and Yaw to the command line.